# How to remove SQL Azure Data Sync objects manually

Tags: sql, t-sql, azure-sql-database

Having given up on SQL Azure Data Sync for synchronizing data between two SQL Azure databases, how can I remove all the DataSync related objects (tables, triggers etc)?

E.g:

```
DataSync.<table>_dss_tracking
DataSync.schema_info_dss
DataSync.scope_config_dss
DataSync.scope_info_dss
```

And all the other objects?  Is there a script that can be run?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

There is an article on msgooroo.com:

https://msgooroo.com/GoorooTHINK/Article/15141/Removing-SQL-Azure-Sync-objects-manually/5215

Essentially the script is as follows:

```
-- Triggers
DECLARE @TRIGGERS_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT
        'DROP TRIGGER [' + SCHEMA_NAME(so.uid) + '].[' +  [so].[name] + '] ' 
        FROM sysobjects AS [so]
        INNER JOIN sysobjects AS so2 ON so.parent_obj = so2.Id
        WHERE   [so].[type] = 'TR'
        AND     [so].name LIKE '%_dss_%_trigger'
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)
PRINT @TRIGGERS_SQL
IF LEN(@TRIGGERS_SQL) > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC (@TRIGGERS_SQL)
END     


-- Tables
DECLARE @TABLES_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT
        'DROP TABLE [' + table_schema + '].[' + table_name + '] ' 
    FROM 
        information_schema.tables where table_schema = 'DataSync' 
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)
PRINT @TABLES_SQL
IF LEN(@TABLES_SQL) > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC (@TABLES_SQL)
END    

-- Stored Procedures
DECLARE @PROC_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = (
    SELECT 'DROP PROCEDURE [' + routine_schema + '].[' + routine_name + '] ' 
    FROM    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES where ROUTINE_SCHEMA = 'DataSync' and routine_type = 'PROCEDURE'
    FOR XML PATH ('')
)
PRINT @PROC_SQL
IF LEN(@PROC_SQL) > 0
BEGIN
    EXEC (@PROC_SQL)
END    


-- Types
DECLARE @TYPE_SQL VARCHAR(MAX) = (
  SELECT
  'DROP TYPE [' + SCHEMA_NAME(so.uid) + '].[' + [so].[name] + '] ' 
  FROM systypes AS [so]
  where [so].name LIKE '%_dss_bulktype%'
  AND SCHEMA_NAME(so.uid) = 'Datasync'
  FOR XML PATH ('')
)
PRINT @TYPE_SQL
IF LEN(@TYPE_SQL) > 0
BEGIN
  EXEC (@TYPE_SQL)
END    


-- Schema
DROP SCHEMA DataSync
```

Comment: Minor correction on the `Types` section: where [ so ].name LIKE '%_dss_bulktype%'. Added `%` towards the end.

Comment: Talked too quickly. Works perfectly on the target DB, but on the source DB there are still about a hundred stored procs and tables left.

Comment: since most people would use a disposable target DB for proof of concept (which then fails) the Target DB is generally smoked.

Answer (score 15):

I recently ran into this issue and while the script in the accepted answer did remove the DataSync schema, it did not remove the dss or TaskHosting schemas nor the symmetric key objects that were preventing me from exporting my database.

I ended up needing to contact Azure support to get everything removed.  Here is the script that they gave me:

```
declare @n char(1)

set @n = char(10)



declare @triggers nvarchar(max)

declare @procedures nvarchar(max)

declare @constraints nvarchar(max)

declare @views nvarchar(max)

declare @FKs nvarchar(max)

declare @tables nvarchar(max)

declare @udt nvarchar(max)



-- triggers

select @triggers = isnull( @triggers + @n, '' ) + 'drop trigger [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.objects

where type in ( 'TR') and name like '%_dss_%'



-- procedures

select @procedures = isnull( @procedures + @n, '' ) + 'drop procedure [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.procedures

where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'



-- check constraints

select @constraints = isnull( @constraints + @n, '' ) + 'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ']    drop constraint [' + name + ']'

from sys.check_constraints

where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'



-- views

select @views = isnull( @views + @n, '' ) + 'drop view [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.views

where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'



-- foreign keys

select @FKs = isnull( @FKs + @n, '' ) + 'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + '] drop constraint [' + name + ']'

from sys.foreign_keys

where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'



-- tables

select @tables = isnull( @tables + @n, '' ) + 'drop table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.tables

where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'



-- user defined types

select @udt = isnull( @udt + @n, '' ) +

    'drop type [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.types

where is_user_defined = 1

and schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

order by system_type_id desc





print @triggers

print @procedures

print @constraints

print @views

print @FKs

print @tables

print @udt



exec sp_executesql @triggers

exec sp_executesql @procedures

exec sp_executesql @constraints

exec sp_executesql @FKs

exec sp_executesql @views

exec sp_executesql @tables

exec sp_executesql @udt



GO

declare @n char(1)

set @n = char(10)

declare @functions nvarchar(max)



-- functions

select @functions = isnull( @functions + @n, '' ) + 'drop function [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'

from sys.objects

where type in ( 'FN', 'IF', 'TF' )

and schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'





print @functions

exec sp_executesql @functions

GO



--update

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [dss]

GO

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [TaskHosting]

GO

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [DataSync]

GO

DROP USER IF EXISTS [##MS_SyncAccount##]

GO

DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_admin]

GO

DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_executor]

GO

DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_reader]

GO





declare @n char(1)

set @n = char(10)





--symmetric_keys

declare @symmetric_keys nvarchar(max)

select @symmetric_keys = isnull( @symmetric_keys + @n, '' ) + 'drop symmetric key [' + name + ']'

from sys.symmetric_keys

where name like 'DataSyncEncryptionKey%'



print @symmetric_keys



exec sp_executesql @symmetric_keys



-- certificates

declare @certificates nvarchar(max)

select @certificates = isnull( @certificates + @n, '' ) + 'drop certificate [' + name + ']'

from sys.certificates

where name like 'DataSyncEncryptionCertificate%'



print @certificates



exec sp_executesql @certificates

GO



print 'Data Sync clean up finished'
```

Comment: found the same script from this url: https://github.com/vitomaz-msft/DataSyncMetadataCleanup/blob/master/Data%20Sync%20complete%20cleanup.sql but it messed up our Azure DB more.

Comment: This worked for me where the first one did not remove everything

Answer (score 3):

After trying a few queries, this is the only one that worked:

```
declare @n char(1)
set @n = char(10)

declare @triggers nvarchar(max)
declare @procedures nvarchar(max)
declare @constraints nvarchar(max)
declare @FKs nvarchar(max)
declare @tables nvarchar(max)
declare @udt nvarchar(max)

-- triggers
select @triggers = isnull( @triggers + @n, '' ) + 'drop trigger [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.objects
where type in ( 'TR') and name like '%_dss_%'

-- procedures
select @procedures = isnull( @procedures + @n, '' ) + 'drop procedure [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.procedures
where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

-- check constraints
select @constraints = isnull( @constraints + @n, '' ) + 'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + ']    drop constraint [' + name + ']'
from sys.check_constraints
where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

-- foreign keys
select @FKs = isnull( @FKs + @n, '' ) + 'alter table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + object_name( parent_object_id ) + '] drop constraint [' + name + ']'
from sys.foreign_keys
where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

-- tables
select @tables = isnull( @tables + @n, '' ) + 'drop table [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.tables
where schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

-- user defined types
select @udt = isnull( @udt + @n, '' ) + 'drop type [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.types
where is_user_defined = 1
and schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'
order by system_type_id desc

print @triggers
print @procedures 
print @constraints 
print @FKs 
print @tables
print @udt 

exec sp_executesql @triggers
exec sp_executesql @procedures 
exec sp_executesql @constraints 
exec sp_executesql @FKs 
exec sp_executesql @tables
exec sp_executesql @udt 

declare @functions nvarchar(max)

-- functions
select @functions = isnull( @functions + @n, '' ) + 'drop function [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.objects
where type in ( 'FN', 'IF', 'TF' )
and schema_name(schema_id) = 'dss' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'TaskHosting' or schema_name(schema_id) = 'DataSync'

print @functions 
exec sp_executesql @functions 

DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [dss]
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [TaskHosting]
DROP SCHEMA IF EXISTS [DataSync]
DROP USER IF EXISTS [##MS_SyncAccount##]
DROP USER IF EXISTS [##MS_SyncResourceManager##]
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_admin]
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_executor]
DROP ROLE IF EXISTS [DataSync_reader]

--symmetric_keys
declare @symmetric_keys nvarchar(max)
select @symmetric_keys = isnull( @symmetric_keys + @n, '' ) + 'drop symmetric key [' + name + ']'
from sys.symmetric_keys
where name like 'DataSyncEncryptionKey%'

print @symmetric_keys 
exec sp_executesql @symmetric_keys 

-- certificates
declare @certificates nvarchar(max)
select @certificates = isnull( @certificates + @n, '' ) + 'drop certificate [' + name + ']'
from sys.certificates
where name like 'DataSyncEncryptionCertificate%'

print @certificates 
exec sp_executesql @certificates 

print 'Data Sync clean up finished'
```

Source: https://github.com/vitomaz-msft/DataSyncMetadataCleanup

Thanks vitomaz!

Comment: Had to switch lines 1 and 2, declare then set, then it worked like a champ! Thanks!

Comment: saved me a lot of trouble! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If your architecture between Azure and SQL Server is still in place - you can simply unregister from the SQL Data Sync Agent which will delete above objects for you.

Comment: This normally works, but in some sync error-state cases, the objects will not be removed, and must be removed manually.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft released this [script](https://github.com/microsoft/sql-server-samples/blob/master/samples/features/sql-data-sync/clean_up_data_sync_objects.sql) a while ago. Handy if you need to remove a single table

```
declare @TableName nvarchar(max)
set @TableName = 'yourTableName'
--In case you wish to delete objects related to all the tables you can uncomment the following:
--set @TableName = ''

-- Generate the script to drop Data Sync tables
select 'drop table [DataSync].['+ st.name+ '];' from sys.tables as st join sys.schemas as ss on ss.schema_id = st.schema_id 
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and st.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to drop Data Sync stored procedures
select 'drop procedure [DataSync].['+ sp.name+ '];' from sys.procedures as sp join sys.schemas as ss on ss.schema_id = sp.schema_id 
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and sp.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to delete Data Sync triggers
select 'drop trigger [' + schema_name(schema_id) + '].[' + name + ']'
from sys.objects where type = 'TR' and name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'

-- Generate the script to delete Data Sync-related udtt
select 'drop type  [DataSync].['+ st.name+ '];' from sys.types as st join sys.schemas as ss on st.schema_id = ss.schema_id 
where ss.name = 'DataSync' and st.name like '%' + @TableName + '_dss_%'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have sync setup on an on premise SQL Server, un-registering the database from the Azure Sync Agent interface will do the necessary cleanup.
[image: Microsoft SQL Data Sync 2.0]