# Remove SQL Azure Data Sync objects manually - Cannot drop schema 'DataSync'

Tags: sql-server, azure

I have done this [How to remove SQL Azure Data Sync objects manually](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25479256/how-to-remove-sql-azure-data-sync-objects-manually#)
but I still have an object I cannot remove

> Msg 3729, Level 16, State 1, Line 72 Cannot drop schema 'DataSync'
>   because it is being referenced by object
>   '_TransactionIndex_7c7a43e4-46a5-43b6-8dfb-603c22e00a94_dss_BulkType_c529b2b4-4232-4083-99b3-2240eb2c106e'.

This obetct is with type_desc = TYPE_TABLE but I can't find where to remove it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is example DDL to drop the table type:

```
DROP TYPE [DataSync].[_TransactionIndex_7c7a43e4-46a5-43b6-8dfb-603c22e00a94_dss_BulkType_c529b2b4-4232-4083-99b3-2240eb2c106e];
```

Comment: nice, thks ! Do you know a place with some knowledge about this ? I'd like to understand a bit more.

Comment: The SQL Server Books Online is the authoritative references to all `T-SQL` statments.  If you click on the ellipsis to the left of the title `DROP TYPE` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174407.aspx) the other `DROP` statements are listed.  Some dependencies "hard", and require dropping objects in dependency order.  Others, like dropping a table referenced by a proc, are "soft" dependencies.  The referencing object will be broken but the delete is still allowed.